# Handlebars precompiled template returning error

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've created a js file from the following handlebars template:

```
<script id="profile-details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <p>{{{blurb}}}</p>
</script>
```

It's compile just fine. Unfortunately, when I try to load it into an html file. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Tried with an number of templates, but always get the same result.

Comment: where do you get this error? In your javascript console?

Comment: download the handlebar.js file again and see of that corrects the error

Comment: @rednaw yes, in the console.